# Functional difference between proxypass and proxypassreverse in Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

The [official document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/urlmapping.html#proxy) states that:

> The `ProxyPass` configures the server to fetch the appropriate documents, while the
> `ProxyPassReverse` directive rewrites redirects originating at `internal.example.com` so that
> they target the appropriate directory on the local server.

From that I understand that `ProxyPassReverse` rewrites the header. But why do you need `ProxyPass` for? Why isn't `ProxyPassReverse` itself  enough? What exactly does `ProxyPass` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProxyPass` by itself enables the reverse proxy functionality and in some cases that is enough.   For example `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/` configures Apache to proxy the site from a back end server.

This works pretty well until the back end wants to issue redirects. Redirects have to be to fully qualified absolute URLs.  To redirect `/foo` to `/bar` the back end would respond with a redirect response with `Location: http://localhost:8080/bar`.  If that got proxied directly to the client, the redirect would break.

One solution to this problem would be to reconfigure the back end to know that it is serving `http://mysite.example` and not `http://localhost:8080`.  Then it could use the correct absolute redirects.  This could even be done dynamically by having the back end examine `X-Forwarded-For` headers that tell it when it is behind a reverse proxy or send the `Host:` header to the backend with [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost).

However, not all back ends support such configuration.  If not you can use the [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directive to change the `Location` header on the response.  That configuration only exists to fix broken redirects from the back end.

Similarly [ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain) is meant to fix when the back end tries to set cookies for the wrong domain.  You can even install [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) to parse all the HTML from the back end and fix any absolute links within the HTML documents.

Answer (score 4):

ProxyPass sends stuff to the origin server from the proxy. ProxyReversePass rewrites the Location: xxxx header in HTTP 3xx responses from the origin.

Answer (score 2):

**ProxyPass [path] [url]**

[path]: It is often the http(s) request from your client. For example, if you want to proxy all requests that start with “/app” to (and from) a backend server, you would specify “/app” as the path.

[url]: The destination URL & port where the requests should be forwarded.

Note that both the [path] request and [url] destination URL & port act in a twofold way and ProxyPass directive has the "reverse" proxy functionality by default. This directive in some cases is more than enough like mentioned by Stephen above.

**ProxyPassReverse**

It is used to fix the the Location header on the response (“reverse” way)  as it is proxied and different. Its parameters often repeat those of the ProxyPass directive.